# splicing a list

Tags: python, string, list

having an issue with a personal hangman project of mine, so im attempting to create a function that will display the current ungessed constonants, and ungessed vowels(first and second parameter) and the third parameter is the letter set player is guessing.

so for example:

```
>>> guessing_function('dfghjkls','ae','g')
'dfhjkls','ae'
```

the output is the letter guessed spliced from either the constoant list or vowel list. 
Sorry for bad english, thank you guys, below is the code i wrote trying to solve but it does not work, it simply returns the same thing you input, it doesnt actually remove the letter from the list.

```
def make_guessed(unguessed_cons,unguessed_vow,letter):

    new_cons=""
    for i in range(0,len(unguessed_cons)):
        if unguessed_cons[i] == letter:
            new_cons = unguessed_cons.replace (unguessed_cons,new_cons,[i])
    return new_cons
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite understand what do u mean, I guess follow is the implementation of guessing_function as u describe, is make_guessed the same as guessing_function?

```
def guessing_function(unguessed_cons,unguessed_vow,letter):
    return unguessed_cons.replace(letter,''),unguessed_vow
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that the ungessed_vow does not properly reprint, for example; if you try guessing_function('abc','def','(d,e, or f)' and you get the following returned:

Comment: This is because the code only works on consonants list. You can slightly modify it like this: 

def guessing_function(unguessed_cons,unguessed_vow,letter):
    return unguessed_cons.replace(letter,''), unguessed_vow.replace(letter, '') And this form is much more concise and elegant than the long answer I provided

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You could make `make_guessed` return `(new_unguessed_cons,new_unguessed_vow)` then update the unguessed variables via:

```
unguessed_cons, unguessed_vow = make_guessed(unguessed_cons, unguessed_vow, letter)
```

At the moment your function only returns `new_unguessed_cons`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_guessed(unguessed_cons, unguessed_vows, letter):

    for con in unguessed_cons:
        if con == letter:
            unguessed_cons = unguessed_cons.replace(letter, '')
            break

    for vow in unguessed_vows:
        if vow == letter:
            unguessed_vows = unguessed_vows.replace(letter, '')
            break

    return unguessed_cons, unguessed_vows
```